# Django distinct query is still returning duplicates

Tags: django

I have a shopping list which I can fill by adding all the ingredients from a recipe. I want to query `Shopping` to see get all unique recipes present in a Shopping List, however my distinct query is returning duplicates?

```
#query
ShoppingItems.objects.filter(user=account, shoppingList=shoppingList, recipe__isnull=False).values('recipe').distinct()
#returns > <ShoppingItemsQuerySet [{'recipe': 47}, {'recipe': 47}, {'recipe': 47}, {'recipe': 47}, {'recipe': 47}, {'recipe': 47}, {'recipe': 47}, {'recipe': 47}, {'recipe': 47}, {'recipe': 47}]>


#shopping/models.py
class ShoppingLists(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class ShoppingItemsQuerySet(models.QuerySet): 
    def by_user_id(self, user_id):
        return self.filter(user_id=user_id)

class ShoppingItemsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ShoppingItemsQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

class ShoppingItems(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shoppingList = models.ForeignKey(ShoppingLists, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=220, blank=True, null=True) # chicken
    objects = ShoppingItemsManager()

# recipes.models.py
class Recipe(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image/', blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=220) # grilled chicken pasta

class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Comment: You have a custom manager on your model, you have a custom queryset class ShoppingItemsQuerySet, can you add this manager/query class to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select distinct values from a specific field then it is recommend to specify that field along with id in distinct that way it will be more precise

To put in code, the distinct in your case would more like be:

```
ShoppingItems.objects.filter(user=account, shoppingList=shoppingList, recipe__isnull=False).distinct('id', 'recipe').values('recipe')
```

Comment: This is returning the same query as my question unfortunately.

Comment: swapping your code around has worked however. Thanks.  ShoppingItems.objects.filter(user=account, shoppingList=shoppingList, recipe__isnull=False).values('recipe').distinct('recipe')

Comment: My pleasure, also apology for the mistake in swapping distinct with values